# Sublime regex replace for a specific character at the beginning of the word

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2

I'm trying to remove character **N** starting at each multiple words. If you check the line below you will notice some words also have character **N**.

For instance changing `N'KISWAJKN'` to `'KISWAJKN'`

```
(2019, N'0081', N'KISWAJKN', N'0001', N'EVELYNE', 12, N'F', N'205', N'GA', N'2019_0081_0001.png')
```

At the end of the replace the above line should look like this:

```
(2019, '0081', 'KISWAJKN', '0001', 'EVELYNE', 12, 'F', '205', 'GA', '2019_0081_0001.png');
```

Also, if possible end each line with a semicolon

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `,\h*\KN(?=')`
- Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
,           # a comma
\h*         # 0 or more horizonal spaces
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
N           # letter N
(?=         # start lookahead, make sure we have after:
  '         # a single quote
)           #end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
(2019, '0081', 'KISWAJKN', '0001', 'EVELYNE', 12, 'F', '205', 'GA', '2019_0081_0001.png')
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]